# iOS 7 / 8 Line Height

Tags: ios, uilabel

I can't find a way to solve this problem. I'm using 3 different UILabels, but the line height is different between iOS7 & iOS8 - is there a workaround? Does anyone have an idea how to solve it? See screenshot attached! I would like to have it as the iOS8 Version

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: And where's the related code?

Comment: It´s just a UILabel and all of them at the same position via Storyboard.